# PHP post to WebAPI

Tags: php, post, web, asp.net-web-api

Well, I know that the headline look simple, but i was looking from 3 days for an example on how to make the `POST` request to `webapi`.

Currently I am using `JQuery` to do my `POST`, but I need some php script to run and talk to my `C# webAPI`, and it seems impossible to find some examples or explain on how to do that.

Someone gave me then Code :

```
$response = file_get_contents('http://localhost:59040/api/Email/SendEmails');
$response = json_decode($response);
echo ($response);
```

But this one does nothing - Not even an error on how to go more into the problem.

I simpley need a php script to make the `POST` request to webapi who gets 1 param(String) and return An ok answer or Error,

Comment: you can do like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5647461/how-do-i-send-a-post-request-with-php

Comment: This works, thanks alot. How can i upvote or put a answer for your comment?

Comment: I glade it worked. When you hover a comment you will see an arrow point up on the left. You may click on it when a comment is useful.

Comment: It seems that if you only have 1 star you cant do that, sorry.

Comment: Grammer & english correction

Comment: Then I @maalls upvoted for you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After Maalls answer from this post [How do I send a POST request with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5647461/how-do-i-send-a-post-request-with-php)

The answer was really simple and the code was the following :

```
$url = 'http://server.com/path';
$data = array('key1' => 'value1', 'key2' => 'value2');

// use key 'http' even if you send the request to https://...
$options = array(
    'http' => array(
        'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'content' => http_build_query($data),
    ),
);
$context  = stream_context_create($options);
$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

var_dump($result);
```

Thanks Maalls  and dbau for the answer :).