# How to add a contact to Dynamics CRM 365 with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-365

It seems that Microsoft Dynamics CRM Web API supports OData and it supports adding new entities e.g. contacts using JavaScript. I tried accessing the API with the following code, but I have two problems. One is cross-origin resource sharing which does not allow my script to execute and the other is that I get access-denied error.

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest()
req.open("POST",encodeURI(clientURL + "/api/data/v8.1/accounts"), true);
req.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
req.setRequestHeader("OData-MaxVersion", "4.0");
req.setRequestHeader("OData-Version", "4.0");
req.onreadystatechange = function () {
 if (this.readyState == 4 /* complete */) {
  req.onreadystatechange = null;
  if (this.status == 204) {
   var accountUri = this.getResponseHeader("OData-EntityId");
   console.log("Created account with URI: "+ accountUri)
  }
  else {
   var error = JSON.parse(this.response).error;
   console.log(error.message);
  }
 }
};
req.send(JSON.stringify({ name: "Sample account" }));
```

Comment: How and when is your script executed? On an entity form, an external application, an embedded HTML iFrame..?

Comment: @DaveClark an external web application on another domain.

Comment: In which case, you'll need to register Dynamics as an application in Azure, and authenticate with Dynamics via ADAL. [Microsoft how-to](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/connect-customer-engagement-web-services-using-oauth).

Comment: @DaveClark, I read some stuff on it. This is an on-premises installation to which I connect via IP address. Is there no way to do operations without registration? What do you think of the idea of creating a simple Web API on the server side (with Xrm toolset) to perform the simple operations I need?

Comment: Hi Jason, so far i don't think you will be able to achieve that. The token release via ADAL works on Azure Ad but not with the on Prem one (i tried this extensively 1year ago without success, it can be that now things changed but i doubt, you will need to check D365 license too because license wise it can be restricted based on the usage you are planning). If you build your own API than the functionality becomes available, but you will need to manage the authentication part on your Api yourself.